# how to limit the number of function each?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have the following object:

```
"data": [
  {
   "label": "dataName",
   "sections": [
     {
      "label": "label sections 1",
      "fields": [
         {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "field 1",
          "value": "value field 1"
         },
         {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "field 2",
          "value": "value field 2"
         }
        ]
      },
    {
      "label": "label sections 2",
      "fields": [
        {
         "id": 5,
         "name": "field 3",
         "value": "value field 3"
        }
       ]
     }
   ]
```

I would like to create a new array by retrieving data from each field.

like this :

```
  array [
      {id: field.id, name: field.name, value: field.value }
      {id: field.id, name: field.name, value: field.value }
  ]
```

I thought I would use each function like this :

```
    _.each(data, function (elt) {
            _.each(elt.ections, function (elt) {
            ....
         })
     });
```

but using the each function I should multiply the functions each.

Is there a solution to get the same result without using several functions each?

If you have a solution ?

Cordially

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the reduce method:

```
var reduceSections = data.reduce((a,b) => (a.concat(b.sections)),[]);
var reduceFields = reduceSections.reduce((a,b) => (a.concat(b.fields)),[]);
var result = reduceFields;
console.log(result);
```

For more information, see

- [MDN JavaScript Reference - Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
- [MDN JavaScript Reference - Array.prototype.concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

## The DEMO

```js
var data = [{
   "label": "dataName",
   "sections": [{
      "label": "label sections 1",
      "fields": [{
          "id": 1,
          "name": "field 1",
          "value": "value field 1"
      },{
          "id": 2,
          "name": "field 2",
          "value": "value field 2"
      }]
   },{
      "label": "label sections 2",
      "fields": [{
         "id": 5,
         "name": "field 3",
         "value": "value field 3"
      }]
   }]
}];
var reduceSections = data.reduce((a,b) => (a.concat(b.sections)),[]);
var reduceFields = reduceSections.reduce((a,b) => (a.concat(b.fields)),[]);
var result = reduceFields;
console.log(result);
```

---

> Only downside is that mutating the original data object will mutate the result in the array. (no shallow cloning)

That may or may not be a downside depending on the application.

If you want to clone the objects:

```
var clone = result.map(obj => Object.assign({},obj));
```

For more information, see

- [MDN JavaScript Reference - Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)
- [MDN JavaScript Reference - Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: This is a really great way of doing this. Only downside is that mutating the original data object will mutate the result in the array. (no shallow cloning)

Comment: @georgeawg that represents a and b, knowing that there can be several "sections"

Comment: @Greg-A [arr.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) works with arrays of any length. If there  are `arr.length` sections, it will concatenate all of them.

Comment: I love how a good [dynamically typed functional language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) can reduce a complex task to just a couple lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

As you are making use of lodash already, you have access to `_.flatMap`, `_.map` and `_.clone`.

Unfortunately, with your data structure, iterating over the arrays in your data is required, but with depending on what you are trying to achieve, there are alternatives to `_.each`.

Assuming you want to join all of cloned entries in `fields`, that are nested in each entry of the array `sections`, that are nested in each entry of the array `data`, you can use the following code:

```
function cloneFields(elt) { return _.map(elt.fields, _.clone) }

var allClonedFields = _.flatMap(data, elt => {
  return _.flatMap(elt.sections, cloneFields);
});
```

The function `cloneFields()` is initialized outside of the loop for performance so that it isn't created on every iteration.

This code will pull out each entry in data, then from that entry pull out each entry in the sections key, then return the clone of each entry in the fields key and then join them into one large array giving the following result:

```
[ { id: 1, name: 'field 1', value: 'value field 1' },
  { id: 2, name: 'field 2', value: 'value field 2' },
  { id: 5, name: 'field 3', value: 'value field 3' } ]
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, you're trying to get the fields property from each element in the array. To do this, take a look at [array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)).

using [array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)), you could do something like this:

```
let array = data.map(x => x.fields);
```

or:

```
let array = data.map(x => (
    {id: x.fields.id,name: x.fields.name, value: x.fields.value }
));
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp

Comment: it does not work because 'fields' is a child of 'sections' and not of 'data'.
The proposed solution considers that fields is a direct child of data

Comment: You can also nest the mapping function like data.map(d => d.sections.map())

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know exactly how "deep" is your object i recommand you using recursive function. Here is what i suggest :

```
function recursivlyCreateObject(data) {
    let result;
    if(Array.isArray(data)) {
        result = [];
        data.forEach(function(element) {
            result.push(recursivlyCreateObject(element));
        });
    } else {
        result = {};
        Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key) {
            result[key] = data[key];
        });
    }
    return result;
}
```

You can test it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/aminotto/31ys2abt/14/)

**EDIT** : note that this won't do much more than a simple console.log over the data but can help you about iterating an object recursivly